# Regex - Invalid target for quantifier

Tags: php, regex

I have this simple regular expression, and I'm testing it on [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/).

```
^(?<name>[a-z0-9\-]+)
```

It should give me an associative array with a `name` field that matches strings that contains `a-z` and `0-9`.

But I get the `?` character underlined in red with that error.

Why?

Comment: looks ok on  http://rubular.com/r/nqBxFkTkxM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well unfortunately, [RegExr v2](http://www.regexr.com/) is dependent on the JS RegExp implementation, which does not support named capture groups. See your working regular expression at [regular expressions 101](http://regex101.com/r/wU3hT2)

Answer (score 1):

Try another regex site:

```
^(?<name>[a-z0-9\-]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wiRL6sPr-64j1Rm9)